# Concurrent ID generation with Loopback

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I try to generate unique identifier for some model, but if I send two or more CREATE request from the client to the API, I end up with the same id

`

```
Model.observe('before save', function(
  ctx, next) {
  Model.find({
        where: {
          parentId: parentId
        }
      }, limit: 1, order:
      'numberIndex DESC'
    },
    function(err, res) {
      let idx = res[0].numberIndex + 1;
      ctx.instance['identifier'] = 'SomePrefix' + idx;
      ctx.instance['numberIndex'] =idx;
      next()
    })
})
`
```

Comment: Is this the code for the create request?

Comment: @Sashi yes, it is. I find the highest numberIndex, increment it, generate an identifier, and set them on the new instance. The problem: if I send two or more create API calls

Comment: I can see that you are getting the index and incrementing it. And you are assigning it with a predix to an identifier. But I dont see the code where you are calling the create method. Could you add that as well?

Comment: It is an 'before save' operation hook https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Operation-hooks.html#before-save. You don't have to have create, it is enough to POST data to the API's endpoint. In the before save operation hook you can edit the payload if you want, but the create happens automatically,

Comment: Ah okay :) Thanks for explaining

Comment: Did you consider to let loopback [generate](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Model-definition-JSON-file.html#id-properties) your ids?

Comment: @IvanSchwarz my model has already a "classical" id for db, relationships, etc. the identifier property is more for the business logic (eg a project hasMany tickets and a ticket's identifier looks like this 'P23\PT00045' where P23 is the project's identifier and PT comes from the ticket's type but I could be something else. I simplified the code, but the generation of the identifier has some complex logic)

Comment: What makes the `identifier` unique? If both create requests concurrently read from the same state of the database, they will get the same information (`numberIndex`) and produce the same `identifier`.

Comment: @IvanSchwarz yep, it is totally wrong approach. Do you have any suggestion to achieve it what I want? I am thinking about generating the ID in the after save hook, then save / updateAttributes the ctx.instance. (and guard against infinite loop). Maybe there is a best practice for this.